# How to locate an element with it's value?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm still trying to make a bot with python and selenium. I'm trying to click on the element with the highest value. The highest value is stored in the `element`
 variable. I tried this script, but selenium doesn't manage to locate it...

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@value="' + value_to_locate + '"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView;", element)
element.click()
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<p data-v-859a1d26="" class="ml-2">632 Bells</p>
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: did u check whether the object exist in the webpage?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp):

> The value attribute specifies the value of an  element.

If you have multiple paragraphs `<p>` with different values, what you really need is getting all the paragraphs' values, sorting them, and clicking the max.

Get multiple elements using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` (note the plural - element**s**) and then use Python to execute the sorting logic.

`element.text` will get you the text content of the element.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your XPath gets screwed up when you are trying to `'//p[@value="' + value_to_locate + '"]'` try something like `"//p[@value='{}']".format(value_to_locate)`

Comment: It tells me this : ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //p[@value='125']``` (125 is the number I wanted to appear there).